# Parent state change not updating child props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to update a child based on the props provided by it's parent.  The way it works right now is that the parent's state contains a variable called 'paused' which is provided to the child like this:

```
class Parent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      history: this.props.history,
      paused: false,
    }
  }
    render() {
        let paused = this.state.paused
        return (
          <ChildContainer
            graph={
              <Child
                paused={paused}
              />
            }
          />
        )
      }
```

Child then uses it like this:

```
render() {
    return (
          <div>
            {'paused:' + this.props.paused}
          </div>
    )
  }
```

Paused is a boolean, the usage above is just for testing, since I couldn't get it to update where I want, the behaviour is the same like this.

Paused is being updated in the parent, but not the child.
I've read a lot of questions like this, but I'm at a loss.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What makes you say it isn't working? What is happening vs what do you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't seem to find a problem with this based on the code you've provided. Here is working proof.

If `ChildContainer` has any logic that could interfere then I could be wrong, but as is, this works:

```js
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      history: this.props.history,
      paused: false,
    }
  }
  render() {
    let paused = this.state.paused // I agree with @Kuo-hsuan Hsu this is unnecessary
    return ( 
      <ChildContainer 
        toggle={() => this.setState({ paused: !this.state.paused })}
        graph={<Child paused={paused}/>}
      />
    )
  }
}

class ChildContainer extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.graph}
        <button onClick={this.props.toggle}>Toggle</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Child extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return ( 
      <div>{'paused:' + this.props.paused}</div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  The mistake I made was using {this.state.graph} not {this.props.graph} in the container.